# Python declaring an array/list static and global

Tags: python, arrays, static, global

I am trying to learn python. I am making a small program that holds some number or string on a static array. I want my function to hold variables in a single array. But after I finished my function, the array is also gone. How can I make my array static in python? I want to change it in several functions.

```
py_ppl = []  

def Dong():

    alc1 = alc.get()
    alc2 = alc1
    alc1 = [0]

    py_ppl.append(alc1[0])
    py_ppl.append(alc2)
```

I mean something like this. I get alc with Tkinter Gui.

Comment: Can you show a bit of your code? Probably want to pass the array as a parameter and return it from each function.  Globals are bad code design in general.

Comment: I am a pretty good programmer, but I am a terrible psychic.  So, if I try to guess at what you have already tried, I will likely not do well. Please help with my short comings by providing the code for what you have already tried.  Even better would be an [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

This example of using class variables may help you. Variables declared in init are local to each instance of the class and variables declared at the top of the class are global to all instances of the class.

```
class funkBox:
    globalToBox = [] # our class variable
    def __init__(self):
        pass         # our do nothing constructor
    def funk(self,elm): # our function 
        self.globalToBox.append(elm)
    def show(self):     # for demonstration
        print(self.globalToBox)

a = funkBox() #create one instance of your function holder
b = funkBox() #and another
a.funk("a")   #call the function on the first instance
b.funk("b")   # call the function again 
a.show()      # show what instance a has 
b.show()      # and b
```

Prints

```
['a', 'b']
['a', 'b']
```